# Align data label right. Horizontal bar chart Vue JS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I tried to align the data label to the right of the canvas. Is there any way to move the labels to the right? Here's how i configure the lables

```
plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          let sum = 0;
          let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
          dataArr.map(data => {
            sum += data;
          });
          let percentage = ((value * 100) / sum).toFixed(2) + "%";
          return percentage;
        },
        color: "#000",
        align: "right",
        anchor: "end",
        offset: "70"
      },
      drawBorder: true
    },
```

[image: Horizontal Bar chart]

Answer (score 0):

The [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. You can use the `afterDraw` hook to draw text directly on the canvas using [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText) as follows:

```
plugins: [{
  afterDraw: chart => {
    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.textAlign = 'left';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.font = "12px Arial";
    let sum = chart.config.data.datasets[0].data.reduce((v, s) => v + s, 0);
    var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
    var yAxis = chart.scales["y-axis-0"];
    yAxis.ticks.forEach((v, i) => {
      var label = chart.data.labels[i];
      var value = chart.data.datasets[0].data[i];
      var x = xAxis.getPixelForValue(value) + 5;
      var y = yAxis.getPixelForTick(i);
      let percent = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2);
      ctx.fillText(label + ' (' + percent + '%)', x, y);
    });
    ctx.restore();
  }
}],
```

You may also have to define some [`padding`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html#padding) at the right of the charts to make sure all labels are displayed on the `canvas`.

```
options: {
  layout: {
    padding: {
      right: 110
    }
  },
```

Please have a look at the runnable code snippet below.

```js
const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.textAlign = 'left';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
      ctx.font = "12px Arial";
      let sum =  chart.config.data.datasets[0].data.reduce((v, s) => v + s, 0);
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales["y-axis-0"];
      yAxis.ticks.forEach((v, i) => {
        var label = chart.data.labels[i];
        var value = chart.data.datasets[0].data[i];
        var x = xAxis.getPixelForValue(value) + 5;
        var y = yAxis.getPixelForTick(i);             
        let percent = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2);
        ctx.fillText(label + ' (' + percent + '%)', x, y);
      });
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['Traffic source 1', 'Traffic source 2', 'Traffic source 3', 'Traffic source 4'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'By Dataset',
      data: [15, 8, 12, 6],
      backgroundColor: ['red', 'lightblue', 'green', 'orange'],
      barPercentage: 1,
      categoryPercentage: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        right: 110
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawTicks: false
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, im using vue js

Comment: what im trying to achieve is to align all the text to be right aligned.